# Able to Launch hbase shell, but unable to work on the shell

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

I initiate the zookeeper, that says zookeeper server started but with the following feedback:

```
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /home/saichanda/zookeeper-3.4.12/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘’: No such file or directory
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
```

then I start the hbase using

```
./bin/start-hbase.sh
```

output:

```
starting master, logging to /usr/local/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-root-master-saichanda-OptiPlex-9020.out
```

then I give the command,

```
./bin/hbase shell
```

this opens the hbase shell but when I create a table in the shell, it throws the following

ERROR:

```
2018-07-28 11:19:07,563 ERROR [main] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper exists failed after 4 attempts
2018-07-28 11:19:07,564 WARN  [main] zookeeper.ZKUtil: hconnection-0x10823d720x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Unable to set watcher on znode (/hbase/hbaseid)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1045)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:220)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:419)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:65)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:105)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionManager.java:905)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:648)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Do we need to have the location of zookeeper logs and hbase in the same directory?

I have got the error, even after setting

```
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
```

but, in the hbase-site.xml file, my path where I want hbase to store its built-in zookeeper files is different from hbase directory

Is that fine to have different addresses or they should be in the same directory?

How to resolve this error, to run hbase shell smoothly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have specified following in hbase-site.xml with valid values. I am assuming this is non-HA setup since you have asked hbase to host its own Zk.

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>{absolute_path}</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>{hostname}</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

After adding this re-start hbase process and see there are no errors in hbase logs. which can be found at ${hbase_home}/logs/

Comment: After I ran the following,
>$ sudo ./bin/hbase shell
I get this...
    `WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable`
ERROR [main] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper exists failed after 4 attempts
WARN  [main] zookeeper.ZKUtil: hconnection-0x14b0e1270x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Unable to set watcher on znode (/hbase/hbaseid)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid

Comment: After which, I got
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 1.2.6.1, rUnknown, Sun Jun  3 23:19:26 CDT 2018

`hbase(main):001:0>`

Comment: I was trying to follow this link (http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/quickstart.html)

When I try to create a table, using create command in hbase shell, I get the following error

`2018-08-01 14:32:22,001 ERROR [main] client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Can't get connection to ZooKeeper: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase`

Comment: WARN [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable this is warning. Ignore.

Comment: See if you are able to see HQuorumPeer running in case hbase embedded zk is running.  ( in case you have mentioned export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
hbase-env.sh ) also try logging in to zk using zkCli.sh